# How to put alert float above navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want alert float above navbar, like this

```
|    navbar        |alert|      navbar         |
```

and alert can be dismissed

not this:

```
|                   alert                      |
|                   navbar                     |
```

this is my code and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqng7e0L/):

```
<div class="alert-float" style=" position: absolute; top: 0; left: 30px; right: 30px; ">
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
    Test alert text
  </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Static top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `z-index: 9999` in `alert` style, you can achieve with your existing code,

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqng7e0L/1/)

```
<div class="alert-float" style=" position: absolute; top: 0; left: 130px; right: 30px; z-index: 9999;width: 65%">
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
    Test alert text
  </div>
</div>
```

the other way around without `z-index: 9999` as follow.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83sLh91k/1/)

You have to put `alert` inside `container`, also made some change as follow

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="alert-float headeralert">
      <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
    Test alert text
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Static top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

and CSS

```
.headeralert{
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 160px;
    right: 30px; 
}
```